# Rendering Tic Tac Toe Cross and Circle in libGDX

Tags: libgdx

I am new in LibGDX. For learning purpose, I am creating TicTacToe and I spent two days to figure out what went wrong with rendering the cross and circle. Whenever I click on the cell, the cross and circle blinking at the same time. It is supposed to print alternately. What I did wrong in the code?
Here is the code

```
package com.mytictactoe;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class MyTicTacToe extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private static final int MAX_FINGERS = 2;

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture tile, circle, cross;
    Vector3 mouse;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    enum Tile { EMPTY,  CROSS,  CIRCLE  }

    final int WIDTH = 480;
    final int HEIGHT = 600;

    int tileSize;
    int boardOffset;
    Tile[][] tiles;
    Tile currentPlayer = Tile.CROSS;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        tiles = new Tile[3][3];
        tileSize = WIDTH / tiles[0].length;
        boardOffset = (HEIGHT - tileSize * tiles.length) / 2;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        tile = new Texture("tile.png");
        circle = new Texture("circle.png");
        cross = new Texture("cross.png");
    }

    public void update(float dt) {

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //processing user input
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FINGERS; i++) {
            if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) { //using polling
                mouse = new Vector3();

                mouse.x = Gdx.input.getX(i);
                mouse.y = Gdx.input.getY(i);

                camera.unproject(mouse);

                if (mouse.y > boardOffset 
                        && mouse.y < boardOffset + tileSize * tiles.length) {
                    int row = (int)((mouse.y - boardOffset) / tileSize);
                    int col = (int)(mouse.x / tileSize);

                    tiles[row][col] = currentPlayer;
                    currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == Tile.CROSS) 
                            ? Tile.CIRCLE : Tile.CROSS;
                }
            }
        }

        batch.begin();
        for (int row = 0; row < tiles.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < tiles[0].length; col++) {
                if (tiles[row][col] == Tile.CIRCLE) {
                    batch.draw(circle,col * tileSize,
                               row * tileSize + boardOffset,
                               tileSize,    tileSize);
                    System.out.println("Circle is printed");
                } else if (tiles[row][col] == Tile.CROSS) {
                    batch.draw(cross,col * tileSize,
                               row * tileSize + boardOffset,
                               tileSize,tileSize);
                    System.out.println("Cross is printed");
                } else {
                    batch.draw(tile, col * tileSize, 
                               row * tileSize + boardOffset,
                               tileSize, tileSize);
                    System.out.println("Tile is printed");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Outside the FOR LOOP");

        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        tile.dispose();
        cross.dispose();
        circle.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);` is redundant, change this:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

for this:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Also, add `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)` before `batch.begin();`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is this `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FINGERS; i++) {
   ...
}
```

I'm not too sure why do you have this `MAX_FINGERS` variable, but since its value is `2`, you are changing twice the `currentPlayer` variable every loop inside this part.

A solution could be:

```
// for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FINGERS; i++) { <-- remove for
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {           //  <-- remove index & use justTouched()
    mouse = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    camera.unproject(mouse);

    if (mouse.y > boardOffset 
            && mouse.y < boardOffset + tileSize * tiles.length) {
        int row = (int)((mouse.y - boardOffset) / tileSize);
        int col = (int)(mouse.x / tileSize);

        tiles[row][col] = currentPlayer;
        currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == Tile.CROSS) ? Tile.CIRCLE : Tile.CROSS;
    }
}
```

And you could reduce your draw section to:

```
for (int row = 0; row < tiles.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < tiles[0].length; col++) {
        Tile t = tiles[row, col];
        Texture tex = t == Tile.EMPTY ? tile : t == Tile.CROSS ? cross : circle;

        batch.draw(tex, col * tileSize, row * tileSize + boardOffset, tileSize, tileSize);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Change `isTouched()` for `justTouched()`

Comment: Your solution does not work, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @FikriAbdul check update, sorry, forgot to change method in `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I allready answered this question on javagaming, as you asked it there to.
You querry the touched tile once per render loop. But a touch most times takes longer then a render loop.
So as soon as you touch a Tile, it starts switching between circle and cross every render loop and when you release it stops switching. If it is Circle or Cross is pretty random as it switches 30 times/second (on 30FPS).
The solution would be to set the Tile only, if it is empty.
This would also make it impossible for the opponent to overwrite your move.

Comment: I rarely check java gaming, seems your solution makes a sense. I am trying to do your way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the clicking problem after googling here and there.

What I did was, I extended InputAdapter class for my Input Listener class

Here is the sample codes

```
package com.mytictactoe;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class MyTicTacToe extends ApplicationAdapter{

   SpriteBatch batch;
   Vector3 mouse;
   OrthographicCamera camera;

   final int WIDTH = 480;
   final int HEIGHT= 600;

   int tileSize;
   int boardOffset;
   int boardHeight;
   Tile[][] tiles;

   boolean turn = true;

   @Override
   public void create () {
       tiles = new Tile[3][3];
       tileSize = WIDTH/tiles[0].length;
       boardOffset =  (HEIGHT-tileSize*tiles.length)/2;
       camera = new OrthographicCamera();
       camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
       batch = new SpriteBatch();

       for(int row=0;row<tiles.length;row++){
           for(int col=0;col<tiles[0].length;col++){
            tiles[row][col] = new Tile(col*tileSize+tileSize/2,
             row*tileSize+boardOffset+tileSize/2,
             tileSize,
             tileSize);
       }
    }
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new MyInputListener(this));
}

public void update(float dt){

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();

    for(int row = 0; row < tiles.length; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < tiles[0].length; col++) {
            tiles[row][col].render(batch);
        }
    }
    batch.end();
}

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
       batch.dispose();
   }
}
```

Tile Class

```
package com.mytictactoe;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;

public class Tile {

    static final int EMPTY      =-1;
    static final int CIRCLE     = 0;
    static final int CROSS      = 1;

    int player = EMPTY;

    float x;
    float y;
    float width;
    float height;

    TextureRegion tile;
    TextureRegion circle;
    TextureRegion cross;

    HashMap<String, TextureAtlas> atlases;
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

    public Tile(float x, float y, float width, float height){
       this.x=x;
       this.y=y;
       this.width=width-4;//4 is tile spacing
       this.height=height-4;

       atlases= new HashMap<String, TextureAtlas>();
       loadAtlas("pack.pack", "pack");
       tile = getAtlas("pack").findRegion("tile");
       circle = getAtlas("pack").findRegion("circle");
       cross = getAtlas("pack").findRegion("cross");
   }

   public void loadAtlas(String path, String key){
       atlases.put(key, new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal(path)));
   }

   public TextureAtlas getAtlas(String key){
       return atlases.get(key);
   }

   public void render(SpriteBatch batch){

       batch.draw(tile,x-width/2,y-height/2, width, height);        
       if(player==CIRCLE){
           batch.draw(circle,x-width/2,y-height/2, width, height);
       }else if(player==CROSS){
           batch.draw(cross,x-width/2,y-height/2, width, height);
       }

   }

   public boolean touched(float x, float y){
       rectangle.set(this.x-width/2, this.y-height/2,width,height);
       return rectangle.contains(x, y);

   }
}
```

Input Listener class

```
package com.mytictactoe;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class MyInputListener extends InputAdapter{
   MyTicTacToe myTicTacToe;
   Vector3 coordinate = new Vector3();

   public MyInputListener(MyTicTacToe myTicTacToe){
       this.myTicTacToe=myTicTacToe;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
       coordinate.set(screenX, screenY, 0);
       myTicTacToe.camera.unproject(coordinate);


       for(int row=0;row<myTicTacToe.tiles.length;row++){
           for(int col=0;col<myTicTacToe.tiles[0].length;col++){
               Tile tile = myTicTacToe.tiles[row][col];

               if(tile.touched(coordinate.x, coordinate.y)){
                   tile.player = myTicTacToe.turn?Tile.CIRCLE:Tile.CROSS;
                   myTicTacToe.turn = !myTicTacToe.turn;
               }
           }
       }
       return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
   }
}
```

hopes help for someone out there :)